# Assistance with Audit Failure 4625 messages caused by WCF netTcpBinding with clientCredentialType Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl, client-certificates

We are having a considerable number of Audit Failure Events (4652) coming through to the Windows Event Log, caused by our WCF services.

**Question**

> Does anyone know why we could be receiving these audit log entries,
>   and how can we stop them from occurring WITHOUT removing certificate
>   security on our end points?

Any assistance **greatly** appreciated!

**Things Tried**

- DisableLoopbackCheck and BackConnectionHostNames registry fixes
- Changes to Behavior configuration such as:
- adding trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" to all authentication elements
- mirroring binding configuration from Service1 to Service2

**Background**

- System utilises two WCF services
- Both hosted as Windows Services
- Running under 'Local System' Account
- Service1 calls into Service2
- Binding and Behavior information at end of this question
- We are using a custom SHA1RSA certificate for Peer Trust
- Certificate is deployed to the Local Trusted People and Trusted Root Certification Authorities

> When Service2 calls into Service1, we get two failed audit entries
>   into the Windows Security Event Log on every call. However, the call succeeds
>   without any issues and data is returned successfully.
>
> Issue only occurs when binding uses 'clientCredentialType="Certificate"' under the security element within WCF binding configuration

**Event Log Entry 1**

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       COMPUTERNAME$
    Account Domain:     DOMAINNAME
    Logon ID:           0x3E7

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:             0xC000006D
    Sub Status:         0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x21c
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   COMPUTERNAME
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Schannel
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

**Event Log Entry 2**

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:           0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
    Status:             0xC000006D
    Sub Status:         0x80090325

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:      0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Schannel
    Authentication Package: Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

**Service1 and Service2 Binding Configuration**

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Binding" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="0" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             transactionFlow="true"
             portSharingEnabled="true"
             transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

**Service1 Behavior Configuration**

```
<behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=CertificateName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"></authentication>
            </clientCertificate>
              <peer>
                <peerAuthentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                <certificate findValue="CN=CertificateName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
              </peer>
          </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

**Service2 Behavior Configuration**

```
<behavior name="Service2Behavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=CertificateName"
                              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"
                              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                              storeName="Root"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"></authentication>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one but I ran into the same issue with a customer following a windows update and changing the security mode to TransportWithMessageCredential, and updating the credential type accordingly, seems to have resolved the issue:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
```

Just thought I'd share in case it helps anyone else.